# ActiveRecord - Avoiding record instantitation while looking up many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models in my Rails 6 / PostgreSQL application which have a many to many relation; `Car` and `Driver`. The goal is to get all records (Cars) which have no association at all (Drivers). At the moment this is done using Ruby (2.6.3) like this:

```
result = []
Car.all.each do |car|
  result << car.id if car.drivers.empty?
end
```

Is there an ActiveRecord expression which avoids instantiating each record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Car.left_joins(:drivers).where(drivers: { id: nil }).pluck(:id)
```

you first [left join](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) cars with drivers to have all the cars and drives associated with them, then you filter cars without drivers in `where` and finally select only one column (`id`) with [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck).

Comment: Right, `left join` is better than `includes` in this case. 

` drivers: { id: nil }` looks better. :)

Comment: Why `.pluck('cars.id')`? There is nothing in the question that warrants it.

Comment: @max the code in question suggests that OP wants to have `car_ids` array as the result of this operation. BTW `.pluck(:id)` would be better, I let myself fix this for you. :)

Comment: In that case you can just use `.ids` instead of `.pluck(:id)`. But usually this is not really a good idea. Just use the scope as is - that way ActiveRecord can use it as a subquery if you use it in a where clause instead of forcing two queryies.